# Arduino not starting after 1.8.10 update

Tags: arduino-ide, ide, software

First off sorry if this is the wrong place.
Yesterday I updated the Arduino IDE to 1.8.10 and I was able to program a couple of hours.
Powering up my laptop today though the IDE is active, I can't switch to it and it shows a white screen if I hover over it in the taskbar below.
When I run the arduino_debug it literally says no error whatsoever it just loads the configuration and start the IDE (5 lines)

Already tried uninstalling and using another version of the IDE

Comment: Delete your Arduino data directory, wherever that happens to be on your operating system of choice...

Comment: Worked! Also made sure the new installation went into a different folder than it was and that solved it... Thank you :)